# IBoutlets nil in swift when using storyboards

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, swift, storyboard

In one of my `ViewController`s, when I get to `viewWillAppear`, all my `IBOutlets` are `nil`, I tried looking at @matt`s solution but it works for nibs not in Storyboards.

This is only a problem when I run the app on devices that are on iOS 7. It doesn't happen on other devices.

Does anyone know why all my `IBOutlet`s in that `viewController` is nil (notice that other `viewController`s works fine.)

**Edit:**
Tried creating a new `ViewController` in the storyboard, with some labels, and a new TestViewController.swift file, and connecting them, still getting nil values, please understand that the rest of the project works just fine.

Comment: "Tried creating a new ViewController" Is there any chance you could make a copy of your project, delete everything except that new ViewController, and post the project to github? Maybe then it would be possible to see what might be going wrong...!

Comment: @matt thanks for trying to help! I've created this: `https://github.com/iamBlueGene/Swift_Storyboard_Bug/tree/ChoozeWithoutLandscapeNavigaitonController`, tried to remove everything irrelevant, please forgive me if I left some stuff :)

Comment: You haven't checked in / committed / pushed any files so your project isn't there. All I can see is your ReadMe. It's very nice but I need the project. :)

Comment: can you post the code how  you instantiate the viewcontroller?

Comment: @matt `https://github.com/iamBlueGene/Swift_Storyboard_Bug/tree/ChoozeWithoutLandscapeNavigaitonController` this link doesnt work for you? I pushed everything, try switching in github to a branch named `ChoozeWithoutLandscapeNavigaitonController` :)

Comment: @SebastianFlückiger I don't, its just a simple VC nothing complex, after checking in `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear`, all the IBOutlets are nil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you're having problems only on iOS 7 is clearly a major clue. I looked at the test project you posted, and my suggestion is that the problem is probably two-fold:

- You've used size classes in your storyboard. But in iOS 7 there are no size classes so that's not backwards-compatible.
- Some of your views, perhaps the views that you're having trouble with, are installed for one size class only — compact height. So on a device / orientation with regular height, those views will be missing and the outlets to them will be nil. Those are what I call *conditional views*.

My guess is that the reason you're having this problem only for this one view controller is that this is probably the only view controller in your storyboard whose view contains any conditional views. Conditional views, like the size classes on which they depend, are not backwards-compatible to iOS 7; so perhaps the whole thing just gives up at nib-loading time, and that's why you don't get any views at all.

Comment: It also doesn't help that your constraints in this scene are invalid - notice the red error signal in the storyboard. However, I don't think that's the source of the issue.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! however most of the view controllers in my project are for one size class only, I will look into your suggestions and update.

Comment: @BlueGene I deliberately didn't look at your real project - only at the sample reduced project you posted for me. The heart of my argument, though, is that you can't use size classes at all in an app destined to run on iOS 7, as they don't exist there. Thus, whatever the details, that's a huge mistake in your approach overall.

Comment: Thanks for making this clear. I wasn't aware that size classes are only available for iOS 7. Thanks!

Comment: So what are you suggesting @matt about fixing this? Disable Size Classes?