# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

I have found many similar questions but none have helped. When I present a View Controller named `TestVCViewController` and do something with a `IBOutlet` `UILabel` declared here I get this error.

I have checked the `IBOutlet` connection and it is connected.

If I simply present the VC (i.e. `IBOutlet` is declared and connected but is not being used), there is no error, however, the view hasn't been loaded as it appears black whereas actually it has a white background.

I checked this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27219058/2500457 and gave the `UILabel` autolayout constraints for all size classes but it didn't help.

*FirstVC.swift*:

```
var nextVC:TestVCViewController
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    nextVC = TestVCViewController()
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

button action:

```
self.nextVC =  TestVCViewController()
self.presentViewController(self.nextVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

*TestVCViewController.swift:*

```
class TestVCViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet  var screwManLABEL: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    screwManLABEL.text = "heyyyy"
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```

I get exception at `screwManLABEL.text = "heyyyy"` and the debugger shows the

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil....

Comment: are you using storyboard/xib? If so, you have to initialize `TestVCViewController ` from the xib/storyboard file or use segue for presentation?

Comment: Yes I am using storyboard. I am not using segues. I am using presentviewcontroller method in the button action as written above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the way you initialize `TestVCViewController`

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("your_VC_ID") as! TestVCViewController
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```