# Size classes not support UI elements for regular width and regular height in IOS

Tags: ios

I developing an iPad application to support landscape only. I have chosen the size classes with Regular Width and Regular Height size. Whenever placing UIView or UI elements and run in the device, It works fine in the IOS 8 but it wont display in the IOS 7. seems looks like size class compatabile issue. Can anyone share your thoughts about how to resolve these UIview to display even in the IOS 7.

Thanks In Advance!!

Comment: It isn't clear what you expect. There are no size classes in iOS 7, so using them is incompatible. If you want to support iOS 7, don't use size classes.

Comment: See also e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27188782/iboutlets-nil-in-swift-when-using-storyboards

Comment: matt, I'd like to develop an iPad app from deployment target 7.0 so do I need to use size class for that?

Answer (score 2):

iOS 7 Does not support size classes.  I had this issue and I resolved it by forcing iOS 8 compatibility.

Unfortunately I think your best bet (which is kind of terrible) would be to branch your code and make two separate storyboards one for iOS7 and one for iOS8.  That being said, given you are only supporting iPad min and iPad normal, you could do two separate storyboards depending on which device it is.

I know neither of these 3 options is ideal but thus is the cost of backwards compatibility.

Summary:

- punt on iOS7
- develop an iOS7 specific version and an iOS8 version
- develop a separate storyboard for iPad mini and iPad Normal

Comment: Thanks! one more question, Can I disable the size class and proceed like the normal storyboard process with the size of 1024 * 768 pixel? Will it impact any of iPad device (I think all devices are in this resolution) or will it impact in any future upcoming device?

Comment: You can disable size classes.  They are optional, although a nice addition.  That being said, if you are running on older development hardware (not the latest greatest mac) they seem to really slow things down.  Honestly they are less useful on the iPad than on the iPhone because there are many more screen sizes on iPhone - also they are frustrating because they don't allow for the differentiation between iPhone 4s and 5 series.

Comment: Thanks Jeff and Matt for the clarification.